# Node.js cli run a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I've just checked a node.js web framework called feathers.js. I followed the example
``` bash

```
$ npm install -g @feathersjs/cli
$ mkdir my-new-app
$ cd my-new-app/
$ feathers generate app
$ npm start
```

In the example `package.json` file, I found a script look like this: `"start": "node src/"`. I read through [node.js cli options](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/cli.html), I didn't found anything relate. So, I want to know how that script work, because normally node.js cli run by `node foo.js`

**edit**: 
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcGlc.png)

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "feathersjsExplore",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "",
  "main": "src",
  "keywords": [
    "feathers"
  ],
  "author": {
    "name": "",
    "email": ""
  },
  "contributors": [],
  "bugs": {},
  "directories": {
    "lib": "src",
    "test": "test/"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^8.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run eslint && npm run mocha",
    "eslint": "eslint src/. test/. --config .eslintrc.json",
    "dev": "nodemon src/",
    "start": "node src/",
    "mocha": "mocha test/ --recursive --exit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@feathersjs/configuration": "^2.0.2",
    "@feathersjs/errors": "^3.3.2",
    "@feathersjs/express": "^1.2.5",
    "@feathersjs/feathers": "^3.2.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "helmet": "^3.13.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "winston": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.5.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: It will run the `index.js` file in that folder or whatever is specified in the folders `package.json` main property or throw `Error: Cannot find module` otherwise. Similar to `require('folder/')` (see https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules). Please specify what you mean by "how that works" though

Comment: I want to know which script under `src` folder will run if I run `npm start`

Comment: Tks @Capricorn, It seems like, the command line will run `src/index.js`.

Comment: Ok, I'll make this an answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will run the `index.js` file in that folder or whatever is specified in the folder's `package.json` main property (https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main).

If none of that can be found an `Error: Cannot find module` will be thrown.

This is a similar logic to `require('folder/')` (see https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules).